# AWS Lambda S3 Bucket Notification via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a Lambda notification via CloudFormation but getting an error about the ARN format being incorrect.

Either my CloudFormation is wrong or it doesn't support the Lambda preview yet.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "LambdaArn": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "arn:aws:lambda:{some-region}:{some-account-id}:function:{some-fn-name}"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "EventArchive": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {
        "NotificationConfiguration": {
          "TopicConfigurations": [
            {
              "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:Put",
              "Topic": {
                "Ref": "LambdaArn"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I push up this CloudFormation I get the message:

```
The ARN is not well formed
```

Does anyone have idea as to what this means? I know the example above has been modified so not to use my *actual* ARN, but in my actual code I've copied the ARN directly from the GUI.

Also, interestingly I was able to create the notification via the AWS console, and so I just assume that AWS CloudFormation doesn't yet support this feature (even though that's not quite clear I don't think when reading the documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-topicconfig.html):

> The Amazon SNS topic to which Amazon S3 reports the specified events.

It appears that although [S3 supports sending events to Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), CloudFormation has not yet caught up. It expects an SNS ARN where you are providing a Lambda function ARN.

For now, it looks like you will have to hook up the event notification manually.

Comment: You can use boto3 to hook it up, but remember that you need a [`lambda.add_permission()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.add_permission) + [`s3.BucketNotification.put()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.BucketNotification.lambda_function_configurations)

Comment: Looks like this is supported now.  I've added a new answer with links to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 25):

It looks like AWS has now released support for notifying lambda functions directly in CloudFormation.

The S3 [`NotificationConfiguration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html) definition used to only include TopicConfigurations but has been updated to include [`LambdaConfigurations`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-lambdaconfig.html) as well.

After adding the NoficationConfiguration, make sure you include a [Lambda::Permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) resource so that S3 is allowed to execute your lambda function.  Here is an example permission that can be used as a template:

```
"PhotoBucketExecuteProcessorPermission": {
    "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
    "Properties" : {
        "Action":"lambda:invokeFunction",
        "FunctionName": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "PhotoProcessor", "Arn" ]},
        "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com",
        "SourceAccount": {"Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" },
        "SourceArn": {
            "Fn::Join": [":", [
                "arn","aws","s3","", ""
                 ,{"Ref" : "PhotoBucketName"}]]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Super helpful. This is one of the least well-documented things in CloudFormation.

Comment: @BKH Isn't using "well documented" and "CloudFormation" in the same sentence a contradiction?

Comment: Hence the “least”. It’s not great, but it’s not horrible.